# How to make codespace port always public when server reload?

Tags: node.js, express, github-codespaces

I am just learning to use Github Codespace for an ExpressJS application, and I have one annoying experience: as I use nodemon, each time the server reload due to file changes, codespace port will revert to private visibility. I always need to mark it as public manually before testing.

[image: How to make it auto public?]

Any configuration to make this port auto public by default?

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/restricting-the-visibility-of-forwarded-ports) helps?

Comment: checking that. Thanks!